# Relation between $R(A)$ (Row space) and $C(A)$ (Column space) of a (mxn) fat matrix and its solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was reading about the row vectors form the row space of any matrix and how the column vectors form the column space of the matrix.

I was wondering what's the relation between $R(A)$ (Row space) and $C(A)$ (Column space) of a (mxn) fat matrix.

For example; Given a $(3\times5)$ matrix $A_{3\times5}$ =

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1& 1 & 1\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 1 & 1 & 1& 1 & 1& 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

We have 3 rows, meaning 3 vectors and all in $R^6$ out of which 2 are independent. While on the other hand we have 6 columns in the column space, meaning 6 vectors and all in $R^3$ out of which only 2 are independent!

1. Does that mean; the row space is a hyperplane of 2 dimension in the 6 dimensional space and, with the basis vectors as the 2 independent vectors shown in the first two rows of the matrix ? And the column space is a 2 dimensional hyperplane in 3 dimensional space.
2. Are both these hyperplane geometrically the same region?
3. When given a system of equations with AX = b ; with A being the 3x5 matrix shown above; can we comment about 'b' and where should it be geometrically in order to attain a solution? e.g $ AX = b$ when b = $ [ 1 1 2 ]^T $ ; has a solution X = $ [1 1 0 0 0 0]^T$ ; what does this mean geometrically? can it be related to the column space as well?
4. When can I call such systems (AX = b) inconsistent? That is having no solution? What is the nature of 'b' then?
5. What is the geometrical significance of $N(A)$ and $R(A)$ ? Also $N(A^T)$ and $C(A)$. I know they are perpendicular respectively; but what geometrical meaning do they have for my specific example?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) yes, and yes. (2) what do  you mean by "geometrically the same region"? All 2-dimensional vector spaces (over the reals) are isomorphic, on the other hand one in a subset of ${\bf R}^6$, the other of a completely different space, ${\bf R}^3$. (3) the word "solution" applies to systems of equations, not to matrices, so the question makes no sense. (4) see (3).

Comment: But the column space of a matrix $A$ is the same thing as the set of vectors $b$ for which $Ax=b$ has a solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually I wanted to ask about the system only. As I have indicated that in AX = b ; where A is that fat matrix. I think I missed it in the question; I will edit it in the original post. Thanks

Comment: What system? A matrix is not a system.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have updated the question. Thanks for the answers and comments.

Comment: OK. As noted, given $A$, the system $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is in the column space of $A$. So, the following are the same: (a) $Ax=b$ is inconsistent; (b) $Ax=b$ has no solution; (c) $b$ is not in the column space of $A$.

Comment: I take it that by $N,R,C$ you mean nullspace, row space, column space, respectively. I don't know what you mean by "geometrical significance", nor by "geometrical meaning". If $A$ is $m\times n$, then $N$ and $R$ are subspaces of ${\bf R}^n$, and if $x$ is in $N$ and $y$ is in $R$ then $x\cdot y=0$. Similarly for $N(A^t)$ and $C$, as subspaces of ${\bf R}^m$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In the column picture of $AX = b$ ; X would be made up of the scaling required by the columns of $A$ to have a linear combination such that they become equal to $b$! What will $X$ be in the row picture?

Comment: Also, can we have a relation or mapping between the $C(A)$ and the $R(A)$ ? I read somewhere that $Ax_{row} = v$ , where v is in the $C(A)$ given that $x_{row}$ is in the $R(A)$ , is this correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the row picture". The column space and the row space have the same dimension, which is called the "rank" of the matrix, but I don't think there's any "natural" mapping. If $Ax=v$, then $v$ is in the column space of $A$, whether $x$ is in the row space or not.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the replies!